# Can we embed our API code In Zoho CRM to integrate any other web application with Zoho CRM like Xero, DocuSign, Fedex and more others

Tags: php, crm, docusignapi, zoho

I have integrated Xero and DocuSign API's in Sugar CRM. Now I want to integrate Xero with Zoho CRM. Can I embed Xero API in Zaho CRM.

In Zoho CRM we can send notification to a rest web service or URL.

I know that I can integrate Xero with Zoho CRM through developing a third party web Application in which I can use Zoho CRM API.

Can we import or export any module or code file from Zoho CRM?

Any other Solution, Suggestion OR Guidelines..

**I mean, Can we add our External API code into Zoho CRM? OR the solution is achieved only using third party integration application using ZOHO CRM API?**

Thanks.

Comment: Can we import or export Zoho module Like in Sugar CRM we can import/export modules?

Answer (score 0):

We have a feature called "Custom Related list" using which you can bring the third party information under a related list of a record.

For example, you can fetch all the invoices from Xero account for a related contact / account using this feature. Please see the below help document for more details,

https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/customization/related-lists.html

> Can we import or export any module or code file from Zoho CRM?

We are not clear about your requirement. Are you asking about fetching the attachments related to a record (Lead/ Contact) in Zoho CRM? if so, then it is possible through Zoho CRM API. You can refer the above help document for more details.

If you are not asking about attachments, then please give more details on your question so that we can assist you accordingly.

Awaiting for your reply.

Regards,
Mahesh.
Zoho CRM.

Comment: I mean, Can we add our External API code into Zoho CRM? OR the solution is achieved only using third party integration application using ZOHO CRM API?

Comment: You can add your API code in 2 places of Zoho CRM. One is for workflow notification and another is in "Custom Related list" as mentioned above. If you need to use your API code for some other requirements, then it can be achieved through third party integration using Zoho CRM APIs. Hope this clarifies.